# Whats the best way to use lock explicit vs implicit?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

Is there any good use case favouring implicit locks by synchronized keyword ?

Comment: As a thumb rule, continous block -> synchronized, distributed code blocks -> locks

Answer (score 1):

Generally the thing to consider is that `synchronized` lock on `this` (either the instance of class depending on if it is a static method). This means that if another class has access to the instance that has the `synchronized` it could lock on the same object.

Therefore it is generally considered best practice to explicitly synchronize / lock on a `private final` field.

Comment: I'm not sure that is what the OP meant by explicit - I understand it as a reference to `Lock` objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the `tryLock`, `lockInterruptibly` or any other specialised methods that are available through lock objects, then using `synchronized` is safer and easier to use: when using a Lock, you need to follow a specific unlocking pattern with a finally block and failure to do so could end up in a lock that never gets released.

If you do need those methods then you don't have a choice...